# joining two pages returning duplicated results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So, I'm trying to join 2 tables to get results from them in one query, but the problem is that this query is displaying duplicate posts, for example there is only one post in posts and two users, it will duplicate that post for both users and duplicate them as if they were

```
$keywords = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['search_prototype']);

$result = $mysqli->query("
SELECT posts.id, posts.content, posts.user_id, posts.date, users.name, users.lastname, users.id, users.avatar_location
FROM posts, users WHERE posts.content LIKE '%$keywords%' OR users.name LIKE '%$keywords%' AND posts.user_id = users.id ORDER BY posts.id DESC");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query by adding **parenthesis** to better group the `OR` pair

```
SELECT posts.id,
       posts.content,
       posts.user_id,
       posts.date, users.name,
       users.lastname,
       users.id, 
       users.avatar_location
FROM posts, users 
WHERE (posts.content LIKE '%$keywords%' OR users.name LIKE '%$keywords%') 
AND posts.user_id = users.id 
ORDER BY posts.id DESC
```

Check this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19cd2/2) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use [LEFT JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html)

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.content, posts.user_id, posts.date, users.name, users.lastname, users.id, users.avatar_location FROM users LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = users.id WHERE posts.content LIKE '%$keywords%' OR users.name LIKE '%$keywords%' ORDER BY posts.id DESC
```

Comment: Thank you.
I added this at the end

`code` SELECT posts.id, posts.content, posts.user_id, posts.date, users.name, users.lastname, users.id, users.avatar_location
        FROM users LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = users.id WHERE posts.content LIKE '%$keywords%' OR users.name LIKE '%$keywords%' AND posts.user_id = users.id ORDER BY posts.id DESC

it was still displaying all users, guess the query is right ? @Yolo

Comment: its not necessary since you already joining posts by user id on users id.